# jquery form mask 4 digits - on selected text - cannot insert

Tags: jquery, regex, input, keypress

what I am trying to do is a simple form field for a postal number input, that would allow the input of max 4 digits.

Check out my jsfiddle. It works fine, the only problem is, that when there are inside full 4 digits and the text inside is selected, I cannot override it when entering number, I have to first hit delete and then insert numbers

http://jsfiddle.net/vCceN/2/

and the other, not realted matter, how can I prevent the user to enter 0 (zero)as the first digit?

---

I used kundan's solution and added (in my opinion) a better soluton for leading zero problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var IsSelect = false;
    $('#fld_1').select(function(){
        IsSelect = true;
    }).keypress(function (event){

        if( event.which==8 || event.which==0 || event.which == 27) return true;
        if($(this).val().length > 3 && !IsSelect) return false;
        if(IsSelect && event.which == 48) return false;
        if($(this).val().length == 0 && event.which == 48) return false;

        var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]");

        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        IsSelect = false;
    });

});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NY3gP/1/)

It works almost perfectly... the only problem is when a user PARTIALLY selects text inside the input box (for example last two digits... than he cannot start writing with a zero, but it should be possible, since he is inserting at the third letter and not at the beginning

Answer (score 3):

it will fix your both the problems

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var IsSelect = false;
  $('#fld_1').select(function(){
     IsSelect = true;
  });
  $('#fld_1').keypress(function (event){

    if( event.which==8 || event.which==0 || event.which == 27) return true;
    if($(this).val().length > 3 && !IsSelect) return false;

    var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]");

    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    IsSelect = false;
  });

  $('#fld_1').keyup(function (event){
    $(this).val(this.value.replace(/\b0+/g, ""));     
  });
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vCceN/74/)

Comment: nice, THANX! I don't like the keup for replacing the leading zero...the isSelect solution is GREAT though! thanx

Comment: I have tested it and have a problem.... it doesn't work when the input is automatically focused (selecting the text)

Comment: OK, for my leading zero problem I added after if($(this).val().length > 3 && !IsSelect);

this:

if(IsSelect && event.which == 48) return false;
if($(this).val().length == 0 && event.which == 48) return false;